# R how to find a series of common values in a vector (identifying growing season)

Tags: r

I'm looking for a way to identify a growing season which consists of a number of days greater than say 60 between the last frost day of spring and the first frost day in the fall. A general version of this problem is this. If I have a vector of numbers like testVec, I want the item numbers of the beginning and end range of values where the number of items is 5 or greater and all of them are greater than 0.

```
testVec <- c(1,3,4,0, 1, -5, 6, 0, 1,3,4,6,7,5,9, 0)
```

In this example, the relevant range is 1,3,4,6,7,5,9 which is `testVec[9]` to `testVec[15]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option could be:

```
testVec[with(rle(testVec > 0), rep(lengths * values >= 5, lengths))]

[1] 1 3 4 6 7 5 9
```

Here, the idea is to, first, create runs of values that are smaller or equal to zero and bigger than zero. Second, it checks whether the runs of values bigger than zero are of length 5 or more. Finally, it subsets the original vector for the runs of values bigger than zero with length 5 or more.

Comment: this is good.  Would you be willing to add some explanation?

Comment: @Ben Bolker sure, provided some explanation :)

Comment: This doesn't quite answer my question. I would also like the id of the starting and ending values. rleid from the answer below looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

**1) rleid**  This also handles any number of sequences including zero.  `rleid(ok)` is a vector the same length as `ok` such that the first run of identical elements is replaced with 1, the second run with 2 and so on.  The result is a list of vectors where each vector has its positions in the original input as its names.

```
library(data.table)

getSeq <- function(x) {
  names(x) <- seq_along(x)
  ok <- x > 0
  s <- split(x[ok], rleid(ok)[ok])
  unname(s)[lengths(s) >= 5]
}

getSeq(testVec)
## [[1]]
##  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 
##  1  3  4  6  7  5  9 

getSeq(numeric(16))
## list()

getSeq(c(testVec, 10 * testVec))
## [[1]]
##  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 
##  1  3  4  6  7  5  9 
## 
## [[2]]
## 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 
## 10 30 40 60 70 50 90
```

If a data frame were desired then following gives the values and which sequence the row came from.  The row names indicate the positions in the original input.

```
gs <- getSeq(c(testVec, 10 * testVec))
names(gs) <- seq_along(gs)
if (length(gs)) stack(gs) else gs
##    values ind
## 9       1   1
## 10      3   1
## 11      4   1
## 12      6   1
## 13      7   1
## 14      5   1
## 15      9   1
## 25     10   2
## 26     30   2
## 27     40   2
## 28     60   2
## 29     70   2
## 30     50   2
## 31     90   2
```

**2) gregexpr** Replace each element that is > 0 with 1 and each other element with 0 pasting the 0's and 1's into a single character string.  Then use `gregexpr` to look for sequences of 1's at least 5 long and for the ith such nonoverlapping sequence return the first positions, `g`, and lengths, `attr(g, "match.length")`.  Define a function `vals` which extracts the values at the required positions from `testVec` of the ith such nonoverlapping sequence returning a list such that the ith component of the list is the ith such sequence.  The names in the output vector are its positions in the input.

```
getSeq2 <- function(x) {
  g <- gregexpr("1{5,}", paste(+(x > 0), collapse = ""))[[1]]
  vals <- function(i) {
    ix <- seq(g[i], length = attr(g, "match.length")[i])
    setNames(x[ix], ix)
  }
  if (length(g) == 1 && g == -1) list() else lapply(seq_along(g), vals)
}

getSeq2(testVec)
## [[1]]
##  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 
##  1  3  4  6  7  5  9
```

The above handles any number of sequences including 0 but if we knew there were exactly one sequence (which is the case for the example in the question) then it could be simplified to the following where the return value is just that vector:

```
g <- gregexpr("1{5,}", paste(+(testVec > 0), collapse = ""))[[1]]
ix <- seq(g, length = attr(g, "match.length"))
setNames(testVec[ix], ix)
##  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 
##  1  3  4  6  7  5  9
```

Comment: One small addition to some extremely useful examples of alternate approaches. g contains the start and end positions of the sequence.

Comment: My addition should have said that the attributes of g contain other useful information - match length in particular.

Answer (score 1):

You could "fix" @tmfmnk's solution like this:

```
f1 <- function(x, threshold, n) {
    range(which(with(rle(x > threshold), rep(lengths * values >= n, lengths))))
}

x <- c(1, 3, 4, 0, 1, -5, 6, 0, 1,3,4,6,7,5,9, 0)
f1(x, 0, 5)
#[1]  9 15
```

But that does not work well when there are multiple runs

```
xx <- c(x, x) 
f1(xx, 0, 5)
#[1]  9 31
```

Here is another, not so concise approach that returns the start and end of the longest run (the first one if there are ties).

```
f2 <- function(x, threshold, n) {
    y <- x > threshold
    y[is.na(y)] <- FALSE
    a <- ave(y, cumsum(!y), FUN=cumsum)
    m <- max(a)
    if (m < n) return (c(NA, NA))
    i <- which(a == m)[1]
    c(i-m+1, i)
}

f2(x, 0, 5)
#[1]  9 15
f2(xx, 0, 5)
#[1]  9 15
```

or with `rle`

```
f3 <- function(x, threshold, n) {
    y <- x > threshold
    r <- rle(y)
    m <- max(r$lengths)
    if (m < n) return (c(NA, NA))
    i <- sum(r$lengths[1:which.max(r$lengths)[1]])
    c(i-max(r$lengths)+1, i)
}
f3(x, 0, 5)
#[1]  9 15
f3(xx, 0, 5)
#[1]  9 15
```

If you wanted the first run that is at least n, that is you do not want a next run, even if it is longer, you could do

```
f4 <- function(x, threshold, n) {
    y <- with(rle(x > threshold), rep(lengths * values >= n, lengths))
    i <- which(y)[1]
    j <- i + which(!y[-c(1:i)])[1] - 1
    c(i, j)
}
```